# jQuery: How to show next section if the first section has completed with valid input

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am new to programming. I have got an issue with my jquery codes.
I have a form that I want to hide some sections of it and do not show until the first section which is input text, be completed then after clicking on the next button first check if all data inputs are completed then show the next section which is dropdown text (part2) and if I pick one of the dropdown text then show next section which is part3.

I tried this code.

```
  <script>
    $(".part2").hide()
    $(".nextBtn").on("click", function(){
    $('input').each(function() { 
    if(!$(this).val()){ alert('Some fields are empty'); return false; }
    else{
    $(".part2").show();}
    
      });
    });
  </script>




         <div class="form">
               <div class="inputfield">
                   <label>First Name</label>
                   <input type="text" class="input" name="get[firstname]">
               </div> <br/>
               <div class="inputfield">
                   <label>Last Name</label>
                   <input type="text" class="input" name="get[lastname]">
               </div> <br/>
               <div class="inputfield">
                   <label>Email Address</label>
                   <input type="text" class="input" name="get[email]">
               </div>
               <div class="inputfield">
                   <label>Phone Number</label>
                   <input type="text" class="input" name="get[phone]">
               </div>

               <button  class="nextBtn">Next</button>

                <section class="part2">
                   <div class="inputfield">
                   <label for="text">Choose a text:</label>
                   <select name="text" id="text">
                       <option value="1">Text1</option>
                       <option value="2">Text2</option>
                   </select>
               </div>

               <section class="part3">
                   <div class="inputfield">
                   <label for="text">Choose a text:</label>
                   <select name="text" id="text">
                       <option value="1">Text1</option>
                       <option value="2">Text2</option>
                   </select>
               </div>
```

Thanks.

Comment: You can refer to [How TO - Form with Multiple Step](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_form_steps.asp)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap all in sections as part2 and part3 and try this, and include one next button in each section in order to know the section will have to show

```
$('.nextBtn').click(function(){
  if ($(this).closest('section').find('input').val() != '') {

    $('section').hide();
    $(this).closest('section').next().show();

 }else {
    console.log('Some fields are empty')
 }

})
```

Comment: Hi marcos.efrem , I just have one more question regarding the above solution code. How can I pick one of the dropdown selection in part2 and as soon as one is picked without the next button, the next section appear?

Comment: First you have to use a unique ID per item, so you have to remove id="text" in select and put different ID in each one, second to get the value when you pass section use $(this).closest('section').find(select).val();